# NextJS Firebase Authentication Context Error

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, next.js, react-context

I am trying to do Firebase auth in a NextJS project but I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'currentUser' of '(0 , _lib_contexts_AuthContext__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.useAuth)(...)' as it is undefined.
   9 | export default function Login() {
  10 |  // const router = useRouter();
> 11 |  const { currentUser, setCurrentUser, login, logout } = useAuth();`
```

This is my AuthContext.js file:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { signOut, signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/compat/auth';
import { auth } from '../../core/firebase';
export const AuthContext = createContext();

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
            setCurrentUser(user);
            setLoading(false);
        });

        return unsubscribe();
    }, []);

    function login(email, password) {
        return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    }

    async function logout() {
        setCurrentUser(null);
        await signOut(auth);
        console.log('logout');
        return;
    }

    function resetPassword(email) {
        return auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
    }

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        setCurrentUser,
        login,
        logout,
        resetPassword,
    };

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{!loading && children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

This is my login.jsx page, somehow it is not getting any of the exported values from the AuthContext file. Every example I have seen uses this destructuring format for getting the values form useAuth() so I am not sure why I am getting this error now

```
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from '../lib/contexts/AuthContext';

export default function Login() {
    
    const { currentUser, setCurrentUser, login, logout } = useAuth();
    

    async function handleLogin(email, password) {
        try {
            await login(email, password);
            
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    function handleLogout() {
        logout();
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div>Currently logged in: {currentUser?.email}</div>
            <Formik
                initialValues={{
                    email: '',
                    password: '',
                }}
                validationSchema={Yup.object({
                    email: Yup.string().email('Invalid email address').required('Required'),
                    password: Yup.string().required('No password provided.'),
                })}
                

                onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        setSubmitting(false);
                    }, 400);
                    handleLogin(values.email, values.password);
                }}>
                <Form>
                    <label className='border border-black' htmlFor='Email'>
                        Email
                    </label>
                    <Field className='border border-black' id='email' name='email' />
                    <ErrorMessage component='a' className='border border-black' name='email' />
                    <label className='border border-black' htmlFor='Email'>
                        Password
                    </label>
                    <Field className='border border-black' id='password' name='password' />
                    <ErrorMessage component='a' className='border border-black' name='password' />
                    <div className='mt-8'>
                        <button
                            disabled={currentUser ? true : false}
                            type='submit'
                            className='border border-black'>
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </Form>
            </Formik>
            <div>
                <button
                    disabled={currentUser ? false : true}
                    className='border border-black'
                    onClick={handleLogout}>
                    Logout
                </button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

I am wrapping the _app.js return in the AuthProvider which seems to be the most common cause for this error.

```
import '../styles/globals.css';
import { AuthProvider } from '../lib/contexts/AuthContext';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </AuthProvider>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Try providing default values for your state properties. `currentUser` is being initialized with useState(), so when you try to destructure will cause the error . i suggest you initialize with `useState({})` or create a default object

Comment: That fixed it thanks! None of the examples I was following do this, they all have blank or null, neither of which worked for me. So I am not sure why those ones worked while mine didn't.